# Resolving sub-dependencies fails for some packages

Tags: node.js, ember.js, google-api, ember-cli, nodemailer

For some npm packages (I have not yet figured out why) the build fails when it tries to resolve transitive dependencies. This happens for example with googleapis.

Here is my ember-cli-build.js:

```
app.import('node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js', {
  using: [{ transformation: 'cjs', as: 'googleapis' }],
});
```

Here is the error output:

```
Unexpected token

...
'fs' is imported by node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'fs' is imported by commonjs-external:fs, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'url' is imported by commonjs-external:url, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/lru-cache/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by commonjs-external:util, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream' is imported by node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream' is imported by commonjs-external:stream, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'fs' is imported by node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
...
and some more...
```

Comment: Hello! and welcome to Ember's corner of stack overflow!! <3 
To better help, can you provide your ember-cli version, ember-source version, and ember-auto-import version? Thanks!

One thing that stands out to me is that it seems like some libraries are trying to import from _node_ packages. _node_ packages are not available in the browser -- but they can be polyfilled.. but I don't know what this means for the behavior of the package. Be sure you are using a "browser version" of whatever dep it is you're trying to use. <3 <3

Comment: ember-cli: 4.9.2 ,
node: 19.0.1 ,
ember-auto-import: 2.5.0

Comment: which ember-source do you have?

Comment: ember-source : 4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

According to the README: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

this isn't meant for use in the browser.

Do you have a server you can use the googelapis with?